# MultiValueDictKeyError at /buyer/register/ end in post and put requests Django rest framework on pythonanywhere

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am a beginner to django, I created eCommerceAPI as a project. The project features CRUD API designed to perform operations like user registration, user login, product management etc. for an ECommerce shopping website.

The application is working fine on my local but I am having issues during post and put request on after deploying it on pythonanywhere.com.

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def register(request):
    name = request.data['name']
    email = request.data['email']
    password = request.data['password']
    address = request.data['address']

    try:
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute('''INSERT into buyer (name, email, password, address) values("''' + name + '", "' + email + '", "' + password + '", "' + address + '")')
        return Response({"Message": "Registration  sucessfull."})
    except db.OperationalError as e:
        return Response(list({'Error': e}), status = 400)
    except db.Error as e:
        return Response(list({'Error': e}), status = 400)
    except:
        return Response({'Error': 'Invalid Parameter'}, status = 400)
```

Complete Traceback

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XK9DE.jpg)

The application is working fine on my local again, can anyone point out the problem here with pythonanywhere.com ??

I tried changing `name = request.data['name']` to:

1. `name = request.POST['name']`
2. `name = request.POST.get('name')`

after surfing about the issue here and there but none of them worked for me.

You can access the live project here: [Click here](https://harrshbamotra.pythonanywhere.com/)
Github link to the project: [Click here]
(https://github.com/HarshBamotra/eCommerceAPI)

Answer (score 1):

Problem is drf static files are not loaded and so there is no js file to send the json to your view. if you test with tools like `postman` or `insomnia` it would work.

Comment: If it is static files, you need to serve them. See https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/StaticFiles/